# Can't link libCURL with OpenSSL

Tags: linux, cross-platform, openssl, libcurl

Building and installing OpenSSL 1.0.0.e worked without problems, all I had to do was to setup the correct compiler in the Makefile.

Compiling libCURL without OpenSSL works fine but when compiling with OpenSSL using

```
./configure --host=mipsel-angstrom-linux PCRECONFIG=/usr/local/crosstoolchain/usr/local/bin/pcre-config --with-openssl
```

I get the following error message:

```
ld: libssl.a(s2_clnt.o): relocation R_MIPS_HI16 against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
libssl.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
```

I tried to compile OpenSSL with `-fPIC` and also tried to use `-fPIC` for libCURL to no avail. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think this works best, since it doesn't involve hacking files.

```
./Configure linux-x86_64 -fPIC
```

I found this by running

```
./config -h
```

and making a few guesses. I confirmed it works by using

```
grep PIC Makefile
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the OpenSSL file called `Configure` in the root of the tarball. Move down to around line 610 and you will see the following for MIPS (find a better match if this is poor):

```
"vxworks-mips","ccmips:-mrtp -mips2 -O -G 0 -B\$(WIND_BASE)/host/\$(WIND_HOST_TYPE)/lib/gcc-lib/ -D_VSB_CONFIG_FILE=\"\$(WIND_BASE)/target/lib/h/config/vsbConfig.h\" -DCPU=MIPS32 -msoft-float -mno-branch-likely -DTOOL_FAMILY=gnu -DTOOL=gnu -fno-builtin -fno-defer-pop -DNO_STRINGS_H -I\$(WIND_BASE)/target/usr/h -I\$(WIND_BASE)/target/h/wrn/coreip::-D_REENTRANT:VXWORKS:-Wl,--defsym,__wrs_rtp_base=0xe0000000 -L \$(WIND_BASE)/target/usr/lib/mips/MIPSI32/sfcommon::${mips32_asm}:o32::::::ranlibmips:",
```

Add `-fPIC` to the options used.

---

Alternately, open the OpenSSL file called `Makefile.org` in the root of the tarball. Move down to around line 60 and you will see the following:

```
CC= gcc
```

Add the following as `CC`:

```
CC= gcc -fPIC
```

Its kind of a hack because you want to do that for `CFLAGS`, but the Makefile does not intake the macro.

---

Or, you can wait until OpenSSL's configure is complete (i.e., after running `./config`), and then open all the makefiles and add it to the `CFLAGS` created from the `Makefile.org` template. Be sure to visit makefiles in subdirectories like `crypto` and `engines`.

---

The final solution for OpenSSL is to add a custom line to `config` and `Configure`. Ben Laurie and other do it when they perform custom builds. Search `config` and `Configure` for "debug-ben" or "ben-debug" or similar.

---

For `libcurl`, I believe that's an automake project. Simply perform the following:

```
$ export CFLAGS="-fPIC"
$ ./config
```